# Semantic software versioning and application design change

Tags: version-control, version, upgrade, updates, semantic-versioning

I have a concern, I do not know which position is the one that increases in the version number of an application when you make changes in the design, whether it is a color change, a menu change or the minimum change.

If, for example, before having made the changes to the design, the version of the application is **1.2.0**. What would be the new version?

Comment: Is semantic versioning even relevant to your case? Who are you maintaining an API contract with?

Comment: A mobile application